# How to get the total social shares of a post

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter, facebook-share, socialshare

I googled a lot but didn't find the answer correctly. I am looking for the specific code snippet that I can use to show the total social shares number of a post like FB, Google, Twitter, Pinterest etc. Something like that

[Here is the Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRI4j.png)

I want to show this number as a text. I do not want to use a plugin. Would you provide me with the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I think it just adds one to a button when somebody clicks on a button (so if they click on the Facebook button it increments) and the total is supposed to be the total clicks on all the buttons.

To achieve this, whenever someone clicks on a button, send a request (probably AJAX) to your server which will record the click in a database or cache. Then use that stored number to display the total.

If you want to actually search and find how many shares you have (without tracking button clicks) then you'll need to learn how to use each social media platform API which is a lot of work. Not to mention many networks don't have APIs to help you do that.